# Replace <pre> tags with <code>

Tags: php, html, parsing, simple-html-dom

What i need to do is to replace all pre tags with code tags.

Example

```
<pre lang="php">
    echo "test";
</pre>
Becomes
<code>
    echo "test";
</code>
<pre lang="html4strict">
    <div id="test">Hello</div>
</pre>
Becomes
<code>
    <div id="test">Hello</div>
</code>
```

And so on..

Default DOM functions of php have a lot of problems because of the greek text inside.
I think Simple HTML DOM Parser is what i need but i cant figure out how to do what i want.
 Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Im moving to a new CMS thats why im writing a script to format all posts to the correct format before inserting into DB. I cant use pre tags in the new CMS.

Comment: you know you can style `pre` however you like with css, you might not have to replace it

Comment: You shouldn't make changes so that you have `<div>` inside `<code>`. Block elements can't be inside inline elements, and different browsers will handle errors like this differently. You're doing well to remove the bad languages though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not KISS (Keep It Simple, Stupid):

```
echo str_replace(
    array('<pre>', '</pre>'),
    array('<code>', '</code>'),
    $your_html_with_pre_tags
);
```

Comment: I think people don't recommend using str_replace and regex to parse big html. Am i mistaken?

Comment: I can guarantee you that it will be faster than the simplehtmldom version!

Comment: You also forgot that <pre> wont match. Its <pre lang="something">

Comment: Yes there was no HTML sample in the question when I answered. You could use regex but I won't recommend it. Are there a lot of different values for lang in your HTML ? If it's always 'php' or 'html' you should keep the `str_replace` solution

Comment: As I said, I'm assuming the list of language is know and easy to get.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). Changing `<pre>` tags to `<code>` should be as simple as:

```
$str = '<pre lang="php">
    echo "test";
</pre>
<pre lang="html4strict">
    <div id="test">Hello</div>
</pre>';
require_once("simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php");
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach($html->find("pre") as $pre) {
    $pre->tag = "code";
    $pre->lang = null; // remove lang attribute?
}
echo $html->outertext;

// <code>
//     echo "test";
// </code>
// <code>
//     <div id="test">Hello</div>
// </code>
```

PS: you should encode the `"`, `<` and `>` characters in your input.

Comment: I ended up using both your example and str_replace from above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just replacing `pre` tags with `code` tags changes the meaning and the rendering essentially and makes the markup invalid, if there are any block-level elements like `div` inside the element. So you need to revise your goal. Check out whether you can actually keep using `pre`. If not, use `<div class=pre>` instead, together with a style sheet that makes it behave like `pre` in rendering. When you just replace `pre` tags with `div` tags, you won’t create syntax errors (the content model of `div` allows anything that `pre` allows, and more).

Regarding the `lang` attribute, `lang="php"` is incorrect (by HTML specs, `lang` attribute specifies the *human* language of the content, using standard language codes), but the idea of coding information about computer language is good. It may help styling and scripting later. HTML5 drafts mention that such information can be coded using a class name that starts with `language-`, e.g. `class="language-php"' (or, when combined with another class name,`class="language-php pre"'.